# Why is List<T> not thread-safe?

Tags: .net, generics, thread-safety

From the following site:

http://crfdesign.net/programming/top-10-differences-between-java-and-c

> Unfortunately, `List<>` is not thread-safe (C#’s `ArrayList` and Java’s
>   `Vector` are thread-safe). C# also has a `Hashtable`; the generic version is:

What makes `List<T>` not thread-safe? Is it implementation problem on .NET framework engineer's part? Or are generics not thread-safe?

Comment: According to MSDN [ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx#threadSafetyToggle) and [List(Of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx#threadSafetyToggle) have the same thread safety. `ArrayList` does provide the [Synchronized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.synchronized.aspx) wrapper however.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You really need to classify Java's Vector's type of thread safety.  Javas Vector is safe to be used from multiple threads because it uses synchronization on the methods.  State will not be corrupted.

However, Java's vector's usefulness is limited from multiple threads without additional synchronization.  For example, consider the simple act of reading an element from a vector

```
Vector vector = getVector();
if ( vector.size() > 0 ) { 
  object first = vector.get(0);
}
```

This method will not corrupt the state of the vector, but it also is not correct.  There is nothing stopping another thread from mutating the vector in between the if statement an the get() call.  This code can and **will** eventually fail because of a race condition.

This type of synchronization is only useful in a handfull of scenarios and it is certainly not cheap.  You pay a noticable price for synchronization even if you don't use multiple threads.

.Net chose not to pay this price by default for a scenario of only limited usefulness.  Instead it chose to implement a lock free List.  Authors are responsible for adding any  synchronization.  It's closer to C++'s model of "pay only for what you use"

I recently wrote a couple of articles on the dangers of using collections with only internal synchronization such as Java's vector.

- [Why are thread safe collections so hard?](http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2009/02/11/why-are-thread-safe-collections-so-hard.aspx)
- [A more usable API for a mutable thread safe collection](http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2009/02/16/a-more-usable-thread-safe-collection.aspx)

Reference Vector thread safety: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp09263.html

Comment: Small note: "lock free" implies "synchronized without any locks", not "no locks". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_free

Comment: I concur with Strilanc: I had to double-take your use of the terminology "lock free".

Comment: Methods like "Count" may be perfectly reasonably and legitimately used on a thread-safe collection, for the purpose of deciding not to bother with something.  For example, if one needs to perform some operation using two items taken from a queue, a perfectly reasonable pattern might be to use a property to check the count (with a read-barrier rather than a lock) and, if the count is sufficient, acquire the lock and check the count again.  If it is still sufficient, perform the operation; otherwise skip it.  Release the lock in any case.

Comment: @supercat your solution involves a lock though and hence is correct. My argument is that `Vector` as coded in the java libraries can't be used safely in the manner you describe without a lock. It's just not possible because every result you find is invalid the moment you read it.

Comment: @JaredPar: My point was that methods like `Count` can often be useful outside of locks, for purposes of early-exiting common cases.

Comment: @supercat what would you ever use it for? I'd very much contend that without a lock methods like Count are virtually worthless (except for logging / tracing). You can't make any predictions based on the value b/c it can change before your code even processes the value.

Comment: @JaredPar: I just gave an example: if before acquiring a lock one checks whether `Count()` contains a value that would be sufficient for what one needs to do, one can avoid a lock acquire/release cycle in the event that there's nothing to do.  If the normal state of affairs is for the collection not to contain enough data to be worth processing, such an optimization can sometimes offer significant benefit.  Occasionally one will check `Count()`, decide to acquire the lock, check `Count()` again, and find that the data has disappeared so there's no longer anything to do, but ...

Comment: ...if that happens the only consequence is the wasted effort acquiring the lock.  If one can avoid that wasted effort in 95% of cases where there's nothing to do, that may be a win even if one doesn't avoid it in all of them.

Comment: @supercat this is still a scenario where the totality of your solution requires a lock. This is the point I'm trying to drive home with my post.  I agree in certain limited scenarios call like `Count` can be used as a cheap lock avoidance trick.  But note this doesn't actually work with `vector` as `size` itself acquires a lock.

Answer (score 21):

Why *would* it be thread-safe? Not every class is. In fact, by default, classes are *not* thread-safe.

Being thread-safe would mean that any operation modifying the list would need to be interlocked against simultaneous access. This would be necessary even for those lists that will only ever be used by a single thread. That would be very inefficient.

Answer (score 9):

It is simply a design decision to implement the types not thread safe. The collections provide the property `SyncRoot` of the interface `ICollection` and the `Synchronized()` method on some collections for explicitly synchronizing the data types.

Use `SyncRoot` to lock an object in multithreaded environments.

```
lock (collection.SyncRoot)
{
   DoSomething(collection);
}
```

Use `collection.Synchronized()` to obtain a thread-safe wrapper for the collection.

Comment: See JaredPar's articles for an explanation of why this is almost certainly not what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

For true thread safety, `List<>` and other collection types would need to be immutable. With the parallel extensions to .NET coming out in .NET 4.0 we'll be seeing thread safe versions of the most commonly used collections.
[Jon Skeet](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/02/07/c-4-part-3-ideas-from-microsoft.aspx) touches on some of this.

Answer (score 2):

The race-condition possibility JaredPar mentions is the scary consequence of relying on Vector's supposed thread-safety.  It's the sort of thing that results in the "every ninth Tuesday the app does something weird"-sort of defect report that will drive you insane.

There are a number of truly thread-safe collections [coming in .Net 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/pfxteam/archive/2009/03/04/9457880.aspx), with an interesting side-effect that they allow single-threaded [modification of the collection while enumerating](http://www.lovethedot.net/2009/03/interesting-side-effect-of-concurrency.html), but there's a [performance hit](http://www.lovethedot.net/2009/04/bit-about-performance-of-concurrent.html) that comes with thread-safety, sometimes a pretty big one.

So the logical thing for a framework developer to do is keep the class as performant as possible for the 95% of users who probably won't be doing threading and rely on those who do multi-thread to know what they have to do to keep it safe.

Answer (score 0):

use SynchronizedCollection it also provides a Constructor-Parameter to use a shared sync :)