# What can I use instead of a Vector in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, vector, thread-safety

It looks like when programming in Java we are not suppose to use Vectors anymore when threads are involved.

What class should I use instead of a Vector when using threads?

```
import java.util.Vector;
Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();
```

Answer (score 17):

> It looks like when programming in Java we are not suppose to use Vectors anymore when threads are involved.

You need to understand *why* using `Vector` is considered to be a bad thing in most contexts.  The reasons are:

- `Vector` synchronizes on every operation.  Most contexts do not require fine-grained synchronization, and as such it is an unwanted performance overhead.
- The `Vector.elements()` method returns an `Enumeration` which does not have fail-fast semantics.

Bringing this back to your question.  The alternatives depend on what your threads are trying to do:

- If the use-case does not require synchronization at all, use `ArrayList`, or `LinkedList`.  You would typically use these if:

  - The list is thread-confined; i.e. only one thread ever can access it.
  - The list requires coarse-grained synchronization; i.e. exclusive access while performing a sequence of operations.  In this case, you would typically create a custom class with an embedded (say) `ArrayList` that is not exposed in the custom classes API.
- If the use-case requires fine-grained synchronization, `Collections.synchronizedList` wrapper is equivalent to a `Vector`.  For example:

  ```
  List<Integer> vec = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Integer>());
  ```

  Alternatively, you could stick with `Vector` and avoid using the `elements()` operation.
- A `CopyOnWriteArrayList` list has the advantage that its iterator supports concurrent modification ... in a sense.  It also scales better if your application mostly performs read the list.  Read operations don't need to explicitly synchronize at all, and typically just need to read a single `volatile` once.  But the flip side is that write operations do synchronize, and are significantly more expensive than a "normal" `ArrayList`.

The other problem with `Vector` and the `Collections.synchronizedList` wrapper is that some use-cases require coarser synchronization; e.g. testing a list's size and conditionally adding an element in a single synchronized operation.  The `Queue` and `Deque` classes provide higher level abstractions that deal with this kind of thing ... for the use-cases involving passing work asynchronously from one thread to another.

---

The bottom line is that there is not one-size-fits-all solution.  You need to understand the concurrency characteristics of your application design, and choose your data structures accordingly.

---

Finally, if you are programming for Java ME, you may be stuck with using `Vector`, depending on what J2ME profile you are targeting.

Comment: @VSH3R See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703990/why-is-c-list-not-thread-safe and http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp09263.html.

Answer (score 5):

```
List<String> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
```

Comment: This is a more-or-less plugin replacement for `Vector`.  But it isn't necessarily the right thing to use.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll have to convert over some of my Vectors to Lists.

Answer (score 5):

For thread-unsafe cases, use `ArrayList`.

For thread-safe cases, use whatever is most appropriate in your case, `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, `Queue`, `BlockingDeque`, etc. To advice more, we need to know how you manipulate things with your collection.

I would recommend against using `Collections.synchronizedList(...)` wrapper as it might not scale well enough (unless you don't care much about scalability). But it all depends on your context.

Comment: Could you explain why `Collections.synchronizedList(...)` doesn't scale?

Comment: If your usage pattern is 99% reads and 1% writes, CopyOnWriteArrayList provides better performance (read COWAL javadoc). But it all depends on the usage pattern.

Comment: Fair enough - an interesting class. I'm not 100% sure I agree with it (i.e. it solves a problem that could probably be solved by using a better design) but sometimes what's ideal and what's practical are two different things. +1

Comment: I was careful enough not to say this applies for all scenarios, I think that's very important point. Studying your problem more thoroughly has never made any damage :)

Answer (score -1):

array, but if you don't know the size, use an implementation of concurrentmap

Comment: assuming you want fast random access to elements (which is why list would be a bad idea)

Comment: The difference is: a Map offers random access by key, a List offers random access by index (more or less efficiently).

Comment: you mean map offers O(log(n)) access whereas List offers O(1)?  then it confounds the discussion to call it a list -- it is an array masquerading in a list interface. if you know the size, an array is clearly the best, easiest to understand choice.  ONLY if you don't know the size your choice is between a map, or grow-able arrays offering somewhat unpredictable performance in a multi-threaded situation.

Answer (score -2):

Use Lists and synchronize them like

```
List<?> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<?>());
```