# What would be the practial usage of vectors?

Tags: java, arraylist, vector, linked-list

Since in modern day programming we use ArrayList more often, what would be a use   case where vector would be used.

Comment: [Why is Java Vector (and Stack) class considered obsolete or deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1386275/12323248)

Comment: "*what would be a use case where vector would be used*", "*is there a case where we shall use Linked list*" - please [ask one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735)

Comment: There is no use case for `Vector`. It was quickly realised that it is a broken class. Its only use these days is seen in academic settings by institutions who haven’t bothered to update their material for 15+ years. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5239271/256196

Comment: Is there a way where the synchronized feature of vector would come in advantage to that of an arraylist? or any case in multi threading where the arraylist being not thread safe being led to data inconsistency?