# Is this algorithm thread safe?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I want to know if the following class is thread safe and works perfectly in multithread context?

```
public class ThreadSafeClass
{
    private List<int> commandList = new List<int>();
    public void AddCommand(int newCommand)
    {
        lock(syncObj) {
          commandList.Add(newCommand);
        }
    }
    public List<int> Split()
    {
        List<int> oldList = commandList;
        commandList = new List<int>();
        return oldList;
    }
}
```

ThreadA periodically call split method, many thread call AddCommand, commandList in the split method is pointing to some list in memory and when the new list is assigned all of its content is in oldList

The purpose of split is that I want to get all of the queued commands and in the next call return rest of them, ... and meanwhile let the application add new items to commandList.

cause I focused on split method I forgot to add lock for add operation cause it is not thread-safe THANKS TO: (can poyrazoğlu) but the question remains for Split

Comment: What is Split() supposed to do? Can you add documentation to your class and it's member functions?

Comment: By your question you should not be writing multi-threaded code, except as a learning experiment. Here is a descent introduction: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446522.aspx You might also do a bit of reading in the System.Threading namespace. This post lists some of the primitives you should learn: http://csharptest.net/?p=323

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here boils down to what you expect the behavior to be. For example, take your split method:

```
public List<int> Split()
{
    List<int> oldList = commandList;
    commandList = new List<int>();
    return oldList;
}
```

There is a period of time between assigning `oldList` and reassigning `commandList` that the `AddCommand` method could add values to `commandList` that will appear in `oldList`:

```
public List<int> Split()
{
    // Say commandList contains 1 and 2

    List<int> oldList = commandList;

    // Now, on another thread, this happens:
    //
    // AddCommand 3
    // AddCommand 4
    // AddCommand 5
    //
    // The list hasn't been reassigned yet, so at this point oldList and
    // commandList both have 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5.

    commandList = new List<int>();

    // Now, commandList is empty, and oldList contains 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5,
    // even though it only contained 1 and 2 when you first assigned it.

    return oldList;
}
```

This sequence demonstrates the fact that `oldList` is not a snapshot containing only the values at the time of its assignment, but can actually be modified between the time it is assigned and the time `commandList` is reassigned.

One thing that is true of this code is that each command you add will be in either `oldList` or `commandList` *exactly once*. You won't experience any repeats no matter how many threads are calling `AddCommand`. This sounds like what you are trying to accomplish, so I think your code is correct as-is.

This works because [.NET reference assignment is atomic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192124/reference-assignment-is-atomic-so-why-is-interlocked-exchangeref-object-object). There is no period of time during the assignment of `commandList` that a call to `AddCommand` could cause the value to be added to more than one list or not be added at all.

Please let me know if I misinterpreted your question.

Comment: That's exactly what i want to know.

Answer (score 4):

The code is not thread safe, as `List.Add` isn't guaranteed to be. (just the first thing - there are other problems).

You are not locking on shared data (any access to `commandList`) either.

Comment: +1, that's what I was trying to confirm but couldn't locate an answer in MSDN.

Comment: @Yuck: "Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe." [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

Comment: It's not important that List.Add is not thread-safe cause oldList has reference to it in split method, if any add operation is take place between creating new list, eventually add operation add its item to one of the oldList or newsList i just want to make sure that no item is lost, will you give me a sequence which it fails

Comment: @Ehsan - `commandList` is assigned to `oldList` in threadA, threadB now calls `AddCommand`, which completes. threadA resumes execution, you lost the added command.

Comment: @Ehsan - you should take a look at the existing thread safe collections in the [`System.Collections.Concurrent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) namespace.

Comment: Dear Oded, I think when threadA assign oldList, when you add and item, it is appear in both list cause they have the same reference, and when the commandList is getting new the oldList has the added item.

Comment: @Ehsan - run your code under multiple threads on multiple CPUs and heavy load and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Having thread-safe class doesn't basically mean your program is thread-safe. Thread safe class just means that you can work with it from multiple threads and it still will be fine. Thread-safety basically means "being consistent on the multithreaded environment".

The List class is not thread safe, so your code is absolutely not thread safe. But the idea is, even if you use thread-safe collection, it doesn't mean your code is thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

No.
Think about the case where a thread calls `AddCommand` while another thread is calling `Split`.  Your new command could potentially be cleared.  You need to synchronize it by using a locking mechansim.

```
// Bad
List oldList = commandList;
commandList.Add(newCommand); // newCommand would get lost.
commandList = new List();
return oldList;
```

Comment: No, because it's simply not in the new `commandList`. `oldList` still has the reference to that `List`, so `newCommand` is in that one.

Comment: No newCommand is in the old list which is acceptable. I want to make sure that no item is get lost in newList or in oldList

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is thread-safe.  You modify shared data, and there's no guard that I can see.

Comment: Can you give me a sequence which it is fails ?

Comment: Sure - one thread calling AddCommand while another calls Split.  What happens?  Is it deterministic?

Answer (score 0):

No.

If one thread starts the operation of "add" while the other is doing the `split` then there's a concurrency issue (hint, although the code for `add` is only one line it is numerous operations by the computer itself)

Answer (score 0):

No the code is not thread safe.By default the classes are not thread safe.

Here is a link [Why is List<T> not thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703990/why-is-c-list-not-thread-safe)

Answer (score 0):

`List<T>` class is not thread-safe whatsoever. Use `SynchronizedCollection<T>` where methods like Add, Remove etc. are thread-safe (enumeration still isn't though, so don't use foreach)

Answer (score 0):

You should sync the access to the list, by locking on an object (and it should be the same object for all methods in this case), where it's safe to use the commandList itself as it is not recreated or anything.

```
    public class ThreadSafeClass
    {
        private object sync = new object();
        private List<int> commandList = new List<int>();
        public void AddCommand(int newCommand)
        {
          lock(sync){
            commandList.Add(newCommand);
          }
        }
        public List<int> Split()
        {
          lock(sync){
            List<int> oldList = commandList;
            commandList = new List<int>();
          }
            return oldList;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, i don't want to pay lock overhead and i believe my class works fine because newly added item is in one of the (oldList, commandList) and it is acceptable. but loosing one item is not, so if you show me a sequence which it loose an item it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if (without locking) two threads call AddCommand? List class itself is not thread safe (unless you are only reading which is not the case), so you either lock, or implement your own list from scratch.

Comment: so whats happening if two thread call AddCommand, assume one of them completes but the other one is not, and in third thread I call split. everything that is actually added in the command list will return and if it is in the middle of add operation it would be queued for the news split command

Comment: Everything is messed up then :) BTW I didn't realize that you were assigning a new list on split, my brain parsed it as Clear(), this way you can't lock on the commandList, so I created an object for sync only. To your question, forget about third thread, you can't code on assumptions, you have to think of every situation. If there are two threads trying to write on (e.g. Add) the same list async, then they, at some times, certainly will fail. There may or may not be a third thread, it doesn't matter.

Comment: so if the problem is Add operation we can just lock the add operation and whats the reason for split ?

Comment: You may be right about that one (my brain is overwhelmed now, and I did not re-think about the lock code after the edit, which as I explained I thought Split was just clearing the List). Anyway, I don't want to say anything about the second lock, yes, I can't see any problems, but it doesn't mean that there can't be. Well just spawn 100 threads with lock removed and make them all access the list at the same time in a big loop, using Split too, it you don't have any problems, then it's very unlikely that it has problems :)

Answer (score 0):

The shape of your class here seems to reveal a desire to solve a variant of the classic producer-consumer problem:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem

I could be misunderstanding your desires.  First, and foremost, as many other people have mentioned, there are no locking mechanisms in your code, and, therefore, there is an inherent *race condition* between the two methods.  If you don't immediately understand what the term "race condition" means, you shouldn't be writing multithreaded code, please go hit the books.  Not trying to be rude here, but I share [Alex's sentiments](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/archive/2005/05/25/408925.aspx).

The question really becomes: what do you want to *do* in a multithreaded scenario with this class?  The answer to this question will guide you towards an appropriate synchronization mechanism for your application.

For the following two examples, let's assume a simple mutex lock, like other people have posted already.

1. What if there are 100 threads all trying to call the `AddCommand(...)` method at the same time?  99 of them will block, especially in a case where the underlying list is large, and is in the middle of a reallocation.  Is that okay?  Is that what you want?  Is that impossible in the application you're working on?
2. In the case of 100 threads, where only one of them would be calling `Split()`, and the other 99 calling `AddCommand(...)`, the one calling `Split()` would get a subset of the list of 99 commands, instead of all of them, since a simple locking structure wouldn't make the call to `Split()` block until **all** the pending `AddCommand(...)` calls are completed, which would (from a data processing perspective) be more ideal.

Now, a more sophisticated locking mechanism may solve these problems; however, these problems **may not exist in your application**, and therefore, don't need to be solved, and a simple locking mechanism will suffice.

Hopefully this helps you get pointed in the right direction.

Comment: commandList is in a thread that periodically split method is called so its not important if returned command list has all of the 100 items or less cause in the next call new items appear in the list, I don't want to be rude here but most of my friends don't understand whats the purpose of the code, everything I wanna know is in the split method, I want to make sure that this method won't loose any item (threadA periodically call split method, many thread call AddCommand) AddCommand needs lock but why lock is required for split ?